# How to retrieve selected value of JSF rich:select control?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, managed-bean

I have a combobox like this:

```
<rich:select id="foo" value="#{fooVo.selectedFoo}" defaultLabel="Please select one">
  <f:selectItems value="#{fooVo.fooList}"/>
</rich:select>
```

Whenver I'm trying to select an entry from the list, `fooVo.selectedFoo` is null. And I found out that the setter of `fooVo.selectedFoo` is not call.

And here is the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="fooVo")
@SessionScoped
public class FooVo {
  private List<SelectItem> fooList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

  private String selectedFoo;

  /** getter and setter **/
}
```

Suppose `selectedFoo` should fill with selected entry, may I know how this issue should be fix?

**Update on 15 Aug '12 - how fooList is updated?**

The construct of the list is in DAO:

```
public List<SelectItem> getFooList() {
  List<SelectItem> newList = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

  Integer theValue = ...;
  String theLabel = ...;
  newList.add(new SelectItem(theValue.toString(), theLabel));
}
```

Then the `newList` will return to BOC and hold by a local variable, after doing some other processing work, this `newList` will move to another ActionBean class like this:

```
public List<SelectItem> processFooList() {
  ...
  List<SelectItem> theList = theDao.getFooList();
  return theList;
}
```

Whereas in ActionBean class, this list will finally reach to managed bean `fooVo` through Spring dependency injection:

```
@ManagedBean(name="theAction")
@SessionScoped
public class ActionBean {

  @ManagedProperty(value="#{fooVo}")
  private FooVo fooVo;

  public void setTheBo(IBoc theBo) {
    this.theBoc = theBo;
    this.FooVo.setFooList(theBo.processFooList());
  }
}
```

I fill in the `fooVo`'s fooList during the setter Spring DI because I want the `fooList` be ready when the page is loaded.

Comment: How do you fill the `fooList` attribute?

Comment: Through the setter method of `setFooList(List<SelectItem> fooList)`.

Comment: I mean how you add the items in your `fooList`: `fooList.add(new SelectItem())` or something similar.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I have update the details execution on fooList.